# How to use 'router' in django and DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to use router in django. But when I tried to import the module and Migrate it to use the router, the following error appears.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'

I definitely imported the module, but I can't understand the error that says there is no module. Can you give me a solution? Here is my code.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from api.views import arduinoViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('arduino', arduinoViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('router.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `router.urls` directly, not as a string

```
path('', include(router.urls)),
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#using-include-with-routers

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
path('', include(router.urls))
```

without quotes (**'**)